# Time between two samplers in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to write a script with two users, 5 second constant time sampler between  each request and 3 iterations.

For Users, Thread Group - No of users 2
For iterations, Thread Group - Loop Count 3
For Timer, Thread Group - Constant Timer 5000ms

```
My Hierarchy is as follows: Test plan
    Thread Group
        Constant Timer
        Logic Controller
            Action 1
            Action 2
    Listener View Result table
```

Is this approach correct, I'm unable to validate if the sampler request time is 5 seconds from the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some extra information to your [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label, for example:

- [`${__threadNum}`](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) function which returns the number of current virtual user
- [`${__jm__Thread Group__idx}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) pre-defined variable which returns current Thread Group iteration

So if you modify your samplers labels to look like:

1. `User: ${__threadNum}, Iteration: ${__jm__Thread Group__idx}, Sampler 1`
2. `User: ${__threadNum}, Iteration: ${__jm__Thread Group__idx}, Sampler 2`

You will be able to see the 5 second intervals between Sampler 1 and Sampler 2 and between iterations.

[image]